# If $a$ and $b$ are the roots of $0=3x^2+4x+9$, $(1+a)(1+b)$ can be expressed in the form $\large \frac uv$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$u$ and $v$ are co prime positive integers. What is the value of $u+v$? This seems like an easy problem, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

$f(x)=3x^2+4x+9$

$f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)$

$f(-x)=(x+a)(x+b)$

$f(-1)=(1+a)(1+b)$

$f(-1)=3-4+9=8$

$\large \frac 81 =\large \frac uv$

$u+v=9$

The answer is supposed to be $11$. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Note: $f(x)=\color{red}{3}(x-a)(x-b)$, not $(x-a)(x-b)$.

Comment: Ahh ok I see thank you

Comment: @Ovi, I'm interested in improving the Brilliant interface to help students figure out their mistakes.  Do you mind sending me an email to get started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)$ is not correct. It should be $f(x)=3(x-a)(x-b)$. Then it works. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your product is $1+(a+b)+ab$.  The sum of the roots is $\frac{-4}{3}$ and the product of the roots is $\frac{9}{3}$.